# What is the JSON schema of a loopback Datasource with PostgreSQL user that has no password?

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, loopback

LoopBack: I'm trying to connect to my DB to API via datasource file in CentOS using this datasource:

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "apidb": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "url": "postgres://postgres@localhost/apidb",
    "database": "apidb",
     "password": "",
    "name": "apidb",
    "user": "postgres",
    "connector": "postgresql"
  }
}
```

I tried many times connecting, but I'm getting an error:

```
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
Connection fails: error: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
It will be retried for the next request.
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

When i type `su - postgres` I can get into the bash with no problems. I have a db name `apidb` which I want to connect to. I tried so far:

1. Deleting the password key.
2. Fixing the url in different structure ( e.g: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/apidb
3. The result [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql/issues/138). Where the pg install is being updated.

Here' what the DB looks like when listed:

```
 apidb| postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres   
       +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/po
stgres +
```

I'm not sure anymore where the error is coming from. Help!

Answer (score 0):

[`Ident` authentication method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html) requires that your OS user name match the PostgreSQL username you wish to connect as.  If that is not the case, you need to choose a different authentication method, or provide a pg_ident.conf which maps OS user to the PostgreSQL user which are allowed.  If you are intending to use ident and it is not working for you, look in the PostgreSQL server log file to see what information it provides about the failure.